# Does Scala have syntax for 0- and 1-tuples?

Tags: scala, tuples

```
scala> val two = (1,2)
two: (Int, Int) = (1,2)

scala> val one = (1,)
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
       val one = (1,)
                    ^

scala> val zero = ()
zero: Unit = ()
```

Is this:

```
val one = Tuple1(5)
```

really the most concise way to write a singleton tuple literal in Scala?  And does `Unit` work like an empty tuple?

Does this inconsistency bother anyone else?

Comment: I'm not sure I can think of a language that has `1` or `0` tuples (to any usable effect).  I also can't think of why you'd want to use them.  A 1-tuple is the value you put into it.  e.g. in Python, `x = (5)` evaluates to `5`.  You can't operate on tuples as you would with lists - i.e. `x.head` or `x.tail` because a tuple of 5 ints is a _different type_ than a tuple with 4 ints.

Comment: In Python the syntax for a tuple of size one is `x = (5,)`. The comma is needed to remove the ambiguity as `x = (5)` indeed evaluates to `x = 5`.

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected :)  Thanks.  I still can't figure out what the heck you'd want it for, though.  In a strongly typed language, this just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The most useful thing I've found for Python's singleton tuple is unpacking collections while simultaneously ensuring that there's exactly one element: `x, = some_list`.  Scala has nice ways of doing this, so the utility doesn't translate.

Comment: I'm writing unit test vectors that will be the arguments to  functions, and I want to verify their size and component types at compile time.  I have functions that take multiple, one, and no parameters, and it would be nice if I could handle them uniformly.  Apparently Scala cannot do that.  IMHO, tuples seem to be one area where static languages stumble: the present inconsistency, the ugly t._1 instead of normal t(1) syntax, difficulty using them as function arguments...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> really the most concise way to write a singleton tuple literal in Scala?

Yes.

> And does Unit work like an empty tuple?

No, since it does not implement `Product`.

> Does this inconsistency bother anyone else?

Not me.

Answer (score 9):

It really is the most concise way to write a tuple with an arity of 1.

In the comments above I see many references to "why Tuple1 is useful".
Tuples in Scala extend the `Product` trait, which lets you iterate over the tuple members.

One can implement a method that has a parameter of type `Product`, and in this case `Tuple1` is the only generic way to iterate fixed size collections with multiple types without losing the type information.

There are other reasons for using `Tuple1`, but this is the most common use-case that I had.

Comment: Makes sense. But it would be nice if a syntactic sugar had existed for creating a Tuple1 but no consistent way (rather than ugly `(1,)` of course) comes to mind! Maybe `Tuple("something")` or `Tuple()` for `Tuple1` and `Tuple0` respectively (By having `apply()` methods in some Object called `Tuple`)?

Answer (score 5):

I have never seen a single use of `Tuple1`. Nor can I imagine one.

In Python, where people do use it, tuples are fixed-size collections. Tuples in Scala are not collections, they are cartesian products of types. So, an `Int x Int` is a `Tuple2[Int, Int]`, or `(Int, Int)` for short. Naturally, an `Int` is an `Int`, and no type is meaningless.

Comment: Do you have a guess why Tuple1 exists?

Comment: @Kipton Sheer completeness, I'd wager. Or, perhaps, because of the long-planned integration of tuples and parameters (which, imho, should have been there from the start). On the other hand, a `Tuple0` would make sense when integrating tuples and parameters.

Comment: This is old, but size 0 and 1 tuples make perfect sense for consistency in iterable situations. The tuple can represent a fixed size sequence. The obvious example that comes to mind (from another language) is Numpy's `shape`, which describes the number of elements in each dimension of a matrix. Obviously we can have 1-dimensional matrices. Can we have zero dimensions? Some would argue yes (numpy allows it). All that said, I'm not aware of any situation where you can't use a list for this (and Scala has immutable lists, which achieve this well).

Comment: @Kat Arguably, that's misusing tuples. A "fixed size sequence" means N times type A, which is not what a tuple is. Granted, a perfect representation would rely on dependent types.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers have given a valid Tuple of 1 element.
For one of zero elements this code could work:

```
object tuple0 extends AnyRef with Product {
     def productArity = 0
     def productElement(n: Int) = throw new IllegalStateException("No element")
     def canEqual(that: Any) = false
}
```