# An integer closed in parentheses in C#?

Tags: c#

I have been using C# for ages, and today I was puzzled to see the following code.

```
int whatIsThis = (0);
```

What does this mean?

I have searched on the net, but no luck so far.

Comment: Do you understand what `int whatIsThis =  (5 + 1) * 2;` means? Do you understand what `int whatIsThis = (5 + 1);` means?

Comment: probably someone just put some parentheses there for no reason whatsoever. my IDE suggests me to remove the parentheses because they're redundant.

Comment: These situations often happen when you first write code with meaningful uses of parentheses and then make slight changes that eventually make the parentheses redundant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author may have been learning about [value tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netcore-3.1), although the variable type of `int` seems to indicate otherwise.

Even if the author had used `var` to infer the type, the parenthesis short hand for construction of tuples doesn't apply to 0 or 1 tuples - the assigned type would still be a scalar int, and the parenthesis around the literal 0 are redundant, as per the other answers.

```
var i = (0); // i is still an int (scalar primitive), not a value tuple
```

In order to create a 1-tuple, you would need to use an explicit constructor, or a factory method to do so:

```
var t1 = new ValueTuple<int>(0);
var t2 = ValueTuple.Create(5);
```

But for 2-tuples and beyond, the parenthesis short-hand will hold true:

```
var t3 = (5, 3);
// access t3.Item1, t3.Item2
```

Simlilarly, deconstruction doesn't work one on 1-tuples:

```
var (a) = (5); // No deconstruct method with 1 out parameters found for int.
```

Deconstruction works only with 2-tuples and beyond:

```
var (a, b) = (5, 3);
```

Comment: Since (0) was valid in earlier versions of the C# language prior to ValueTuples, syntax like (0) could not be repurposed as a constructor for a 1-tuple.

In any event, the usefulness of 0 and 1-tuples is [primarily academic and debatable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7207527)

Comment: 0-tuples are useful for using `Func<T>` to represent a `void` method (and without duplicating generic code for both `Action` and `Func`), and 1-tuples are useful when you want a single "named" return value when the method name doesn't describe the return value - or if you're refactoring and can't decide if a method should have 1 or 2 return values, but when you don't want to go through the effort to update all of the `return` statements (though implicit conversion from `T` to a `ValueTuple<T>` would be nice!)

Comment: Yes, I've also seen 0-tuples for representing 'Unit' in languages which don't have this as a first-class implementation, although other representations are possible (e.g. custom struct or class). Good point about the naming!

Answer (score 13):

The parenthesis in this case are entirely redundant. These statements are all semantically identical:

```
int whatIsThis = 0;
int whatIsThis = (0);
int whatIsThis = ((0));
int whatIsThis = (((0))); // etc
```

That said, in C# you do sometimes need to use parenthesis when you're specifying a negative integer literal to avoid ambiguity with the unary vs. binary `-` operators. It's possible this code was using a negative literal earlier and the author didn't remove the parens when they changed it to use a zero.

Answer (score 1):

> What does this mean?

Simple.

> var x = 1+2;

is legal. You can assign a formula. It is in this case (constants) evaluated at compile time.

> var x = (1+2);

is legal too - you can group as you have / should have learned in maths. Determines priority, obviously useless as long as you have only one group.

> var x = (2);

is basically a group with one constant. It looks idiotic - and it is basically optimized out and a surplus, but it is mathematically and by language rules legal. Simply no-one bothers to forbid it.

It is identical to:

> var x = 2;